# Azure Synapse query optimization: Join of 3 huge tables

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, azure-synapse

One of the SP involving the join of 3 tables and then putting it into a new table is taking forever to process.
Table1 has 86,12,44,940 records (84gb). Table2 has 72,98,41,882 records. (56gb)
Table 3 has 46140 records.

Any idea how can I process this faster?

Query(SP) below:

```
insert into newtable
select ... 
from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
join t3 on t2.id2 = t3.id2
```

id2 has a lot of duplicate values(not unique) but all records are required.

The total records will increase in the final table after the join since id2 is not unique.
I ran it for 5 hours and it failed because of query timeout. There is a date record as well through which i can process the results batch by batch, but not sure how long it will take.

Answer (score 0):

*Query Optimization* is one of the solutions for above issue there are many query optimization ways one of which is Clustered column store index

Note you can refer other optimization techniques  in [Optimising Query Performance — In Azure Synapse Analytics | by Samueldavidwinter | Medium](https://medium.com/@samueldavidwinter/optimising-query-performance-in-azure-synapse-analytics-9aa6a58e3fa1)

***Clustered column store index***
A clustered columnstore index is the **physical storage for the entire table**. To reduce fragmentation of the column segments and improve performance, the columnstore index might store some data temporarily into a clustered index called a deltastore and a B-tree list of IDs for deleted rows. for more information check the following links
[Columnstore indexes - Query performance - SQL Server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-query-performance?view=sql-server-ver16)

[Performance tuning with ordered clustered columnstore index - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/performance-tuning-ordered-cci)

I have created a demo table Account, Acc, Persons and inserted some random repeated values into it

Account Table

[image]

Acc Table

[image]

Persons Table

[image]

Now, it should be converted to store data in 'columnstore' in order to reduce the storage space

```sql
CREATE  TABLE account2
WITH
(
DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
,CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
AS
SELECT *
FROM account;
```

Apply the above query for all three tables. Now compare sizes of the table before and after performing Clustered Columstore index using the following query:

```sql
exec sp_spaceused 'account'
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Joining these three indexed tables to insert results into fourth table demo

```sql
select * into finalt from account2 t1 inner  join Persons2 t2 on t1.ACCOUNTKEY = t2.PersonID join acc2 t3 on t2.PersonID = t3.IKEY
```

Join condition for table applied for clustered column takes less time than for the table not applied as seen below

[image]

[image]